# using predict in r on future dates when other values are missing

Tags: r

I have data about different variables, the data contains their values thru the last year 01.01.2020-24.07.2021 I want to predict the x1 variable thru the dates 30.07.2021-05.08.2021
when I use predict in R it shows that the other variables are missing how can I fix that?

```
Dt
startdate <- as.Date("2020/01/01")
enddate <- as.Date("2021/07/30")
z <-seq(enddate,by="day",length.out=6 ) 
z
c <- seq(startdate,by="day",length.out=486 )
c
sub_Dt <- Dt[date %in% c,]
#predict
sub_Dt_2021 <- Dt[date %in% z,] 
mod1 <- lm(transportation_index_avg ~.,
           data = sub_Dt)                        

sub_Dt_2021$pred_mod1 <- (predict(mod1, sub_Dt_2021))*0.95
```

| date | transportation_index_avg | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 34 | 134 | 384 | 24 |
| 2020-01-02 | 42 | 542 | 432 | 35 |
| 2020-01-03 | 34 | 634 | 348 | 25 |
| 2020-01-03 | 42 | 742 | 742 | 87 |
| 2021-07-24 | 34 | 634 | 314 | 97 |
| 2021-07-25 | 42 | 242 | 462 | 37 |

Comment: In short: You cannot, because we cannot predict values based on data we do not have. You could either predict `x2`, `x3` and `x4` for the future first or predict `transporation_index_avg` based only on `date` but not on the other values. People will likely show you how to do that if you post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: and how can I predict the other variables?

Comment: Either based on `date` alone or based on your knowledge about what `x2` to `x4` are in the real world and how we expect them to behave in the future. As I said above, a minimal reproducible example helps. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example